# Get checkbox value from parent window into pop up window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, popup

I am trying to display the form fields filled from the parent JSP into a pop up to inform the user how much of the form is filled.
So far I'm able to display just the textfield values. I'm not able to display the checkbox values.Below is an example of the code I've written. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Parent.jsp

```
Name: <input type="text" id="name"/>
Gender: Male<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="male"/>
        Female<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="female"/>
<a href="PopUp.jsp" target="_blank">View</a>
```

PopUp.jsp

```
<script>
function setThis(){
    document.getElementById("name").value=window.opener.document.getElementById("name").value;
    if(window.opener.document.getElementById("male").checked)
        document.getElementById("male").checked=true;
    if(window.opener.document.getElementById("female").checked)
        document.getElementById("female").checked=true;
}

</script>
<body onload="setThis();">
Name: <input type="text" id="name"/>
 Gender: Male<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="male"/>
        Female<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="female"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code slightly modified (look at the href link), this code worked for me.

```
    <html>
    <script>
    function openpopup() {
        window.open('try2.html');
        return false;
    }

    </script>
        <body>
            <form>

              Name: <input type="text" id="name"/>
        Gender: Male<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="male"/>
            Female<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="female"/><br />
     <a href="" onclick="javascript:return openpopup()">View</a>
   </form>
```

and my try2.html (your popup.jsp)

```
    <html>
    <script>


    function setThis(){
        document.getElementById("name").value=window.opener.document.getElementById("name").value;
        if(window.opener.document.getElementById("male").checked)
            document.getElementById("male").checked=true;
        if(window.opener.document.getElementById("female").checked)
            document.getElementById("female").checked=true;

    }
    </script>
        <body onload="setThis()">
            <form>

    Name: <input type="text" id="name"/>
     Gender: Male<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="male"/>
            Female<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="female"/>
           </form>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Having said that, I have steered away from using popup windows and rather use in page popup dialogs.  Most the time I use JQuery UI Dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for the help. I added a semicolon after setThis(). It started working when I removed it. I always thought that it never mattered whether there was a  semi colon or not. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you open your popup with the window.open, your window.opener should be working.
Here is a very crude example that will copy the checkbox html from the parent.
Parent (try.html)

```
<html>
<script>
function openpopup() {
    window.open('try2.html');
    return false;
}

</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <a href="" onclick="javascript:return openpopup()">popup</a>
        <input id='cb' type=checkbox>

   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Child page (try2.html)

```
function loaded() {
    if(window.opener) {
    document.getElementById('tb').value =   window.opener.document.getElementById("cb").outerHTML
    }
}
</script>
    <body onload="loaded()">
        <form>
            <input type=text id=tb>
       </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Bindrid, this tip is good, but it still doesn't solve the problem getting the checkbox values to display.

Comment: I tried your code. It still does not display the checkbox values. Could I be missing something else?